# Automatically insert or update in case of "create_time" and "update_time" column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

When I was working on an oracle project a while ago, that needs to create a table containing both "created_time" and "updated_time" columns,  I remember there is a way to define these 2 special columns, so that during the run-time, it will

- automatically populate the "created_time" value in case a new row is being inserted
- automatically populate the "update_time"  value in case a new row is being inserted or an existing row is being updated.

Because of that, I don't need to populate any data into these 2 columns myself during the run-time.

Is that the same behavior for MYSQL DB ?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Yes, and even if there wasn't, you can use triggers to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
created_time  TIMESTAMP  DEFAULT     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
updated_time  TIMESTAMP   ON UPDATE  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: There were some limitations before MySQL before 5.6,